# Django: name 'SignupFormExtra' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I currently have django-userena installed and I am trying to override the default sign up form with a custom one so I can have extra fields, but being new to django, I happen to be stuck. After following the guide from the documentation from userena I have an app called accounts. In that app I created 'forms.py' and put the following info:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from userena.forms import SignupForm

class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
    """
    A form to demonstrate how to add extra fields to the signup form, in this
    case adding the first and last name.


    """
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'),
                                 max_length=30,
                                 required=True)

    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Last name'),
                                max_length=30,
                                required=True)
    industry = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Industry'),
                                max_length=50,
                                required=False)
    occupation = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Occupation'),
                                max_length=50,
                                required=False)
    bio = forms.TextField(label=_(u'Bio'),
                                required=True)
    skills = forms.TextField(label=_(u'Skills'),
                                required=False)
    interests = forms.TextField(label=_(u'Interests'),
                                max_length=50,
                                required=False)
    phone = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Phone'),
                                max_length=10,
                                required=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        """

        A bit of hackery to get the first name and last name at the top of the
        form instead at the end.

        """
        super(SignupFormExtra, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        # Put the first and last name at the top
        new_order = self.fields.keyOrder[:-2]
        new_order.insert(0, 'first_name')
        new_order.insert(1, 'last_name')
        new_order.insert(2, 'industry')
        new_order.insert(3, 'occupation')
        new_order.insert(4, 'bio')
        new_order.insert(5, 'skills')
        new_order.insert(6, 'interests')
        new_order.insert(7, 'phone')
        self.fields.keyOrder = new_order

    def save(self):
        """
        Override the save method to save the first and last name to the user
        field.

        """
        # First save the parent form and get the user.
        new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()

        new_user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        new_user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        new_user.industry = self.cleaned_data['industry']
        new_user.occupation = self.cleaned_data['occupation']
        new_user.bio = self.cleaned_data['bio']      
        new_user.skills = self.cleaned_data['skills']
        new_user.interests = self.cleaned_data['interests']
        new_user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']  
        new_user.save()

        # Userena expects to get the new user from this form, so return the new
        # user.
        return new_user
```

and then added the following to my projects urls.py

```
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^accounts/signup/$',
    'userena.views.signup',
    {'signup_form': SignupFormExtra})
    (r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
```

However I must have messed up in my urls configuration because I am being displayed with a helpful error message:

> name 'SignupFormExtra' is not defined

which says line 14 in my urls.py which is the following line:

```
{'signup_form': SignupFormExtra})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to import `SignupFormExtra` into your `urls.py`.

At the top of your `urls.py`:

```
from accounts.forms import SignupFormExtra
```

Make sure you have the proper relative path to your `forms.py`. This assumes your `urls.py` is in the same directory as `forms.py`.

EDIT:

Just re-read your question and saw the `forms.py` was in an app named `accounts`. I adjusted the answer so you're importing from `accounts.forms`.